# Вывод в GPIO пульсации с подпульсациями. RaspberryPi3B+ , Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Мне нужен сигнал с разных GPIO примерно такой формы. Пульсация внутри пульсации [image]

Как я могу сделать это со своего Raspberry 3 B+? Пробовал библиотеку RPIO, но она стара как мир, и даже форк у многих на новых RPi не работает. И как поменялись выходы пин с тех пор - не понятно.

```
from RPIO import PWM
servo = PWM.Servo()
servo.set_servo(12, 10000)
PWM.add_channel_pulse(0, 12, start=200, width=2000)
```

В итоге нет сигнала на 12 пине. См картинку. Ни на одном из них. Хотя процесс какой то идёт, программа не выдает ошибок. 
[image]
Запутался в этой старой библиотеке я крепко. И увидел что вообщем то есть и стандартная библиотека для RPi, которая позволяет софтварно ШИМ делать. Но не увидел я, где можно подцикл добавить - только вроде бы скважность и частоту можно. А надо бы как на картинке сверху.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта `GPIO` неправильные. В реальности картинка выглядит вот так:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть 12-й контролируемый пин - это по сути 19-я нога в железке.

Ещё очень важный момент! Raspberry PI имеет всего 1 PWM ногу!!!

То есть для точного управления сервомоторами Raspberry не подходит вовсе. Я занимаюсь разработкой вендинговых аппаратов, и когда у меня стояла задача управлять 25-ю сервами с точностью 1 к 1, то есть любое коллизийное движение сервомотора заставляло аппарат сбрасывать игрушку (недоработка технических инженеров), мне пришлось сделать связку Raspberry + Arduino. Так как Arduino имеет более точный PWM сигнал на ногах.